# Sorting by two fields mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have an object Report that contains two integer fields: Month and Year.
I need to sort it by "date"

```
Report.desc(:year).desc(:month).each do |a|
puts a.year.to_s + " " + a.month.to_s
end
```

results:

```
2011 12
2011 11
2012 7
2012 6
2012 5
2012 4
2012 3
2012 2
2012 1
```

While I would think to get

```
2012 7
2012 6
2012 5
2012 4
2012 3
2012 2
2012 1
2011 12
2011 11
```

What am I doing wrong?

The Mongoid Criteria looks like:

```
irb(main):043:0> Report.desc(:year).desc(:month)

    => #<Mongoid::Criteria
       selector: {},
       options:  {:sort=>{"year"=>-1, "month"=>-1}},
       class:    Report,
       embedded: true>
```

Comment: Did you try `.desc(:year, :month)`? Reading the [docs for Origin](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html#sorting) make me think that is what you needed. This assumes you are using Mongoid 3. I think what might have been happening was that your second `desc` call was overriding your first one. Mongoid constructs a single query from your entire search, so it should be not be doing one after the other. It doesn't appear that way from your criteria though, which is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you get is only sorted by month not by the whole date(thus the result you get). Maybe use the sort_by method with a body that takes into account both the year and the month?
Something like:

```
Report.sort_by{|t| [-t.year, -t.month]}
```

EDIT: I am using the negatives of both the year and the month to achieve decreasing order.

Comment: That works just fine, thanks, but what was the problem in my example?

Comment: As I said after sorting by year, you sort by month. This happens one after the other not at the same time. As a result you only have the array sorted by month ignoring the year. Btw reversing the sorting to first happen by year and then by month would suffice I believe.

Comment: Strange ... I've updated the question with a mongoid criteria, and still I can't understand where is a problem, since there also I'm sorting by 2 fields together...

Comment: @BenjaminHarel please note that the order of applying the sort does matter. Is there a way in mogoid criteria to set the order of the sorting criterias?

Comment: I don't know seems {:sort=>{"year"=>-1, "month"=>-1}} does have order.  Anyway Your suggestion works just fine to me, thanks :-)